# Mule dev-kit and custom connector

Tags: mule, connector

I am experimenting with Mule Custom connectors these days. I followed all the steps described at [Barn Connector](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Tutorial+-+Barn+Connector) to see a sample working connector. It doesn't download core mule api and its related libraries and modules, so compilation errors are occurred. Can any provide me the solution?

**EDIT:**
Mule devkit annotations are not resolved:

```
import org.mule.api.annotations.ConnectionStrategy;
import org.mule.api.annotations.Connector;
import org.mule.api.annotations.Configurable;
import org.mule.api.annotations.Processor;
import org.mule.api.annotations.param.Default;
```

The above imports are not resolved.

Comment: What is "it" that doesn't download? Maven? What error do you get?

Comment: Yes, it is related to Maven.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the error(s) you're getting from Maven.

Comment: Maven build is successful, no errors, however, it doesn't download the mentioned dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If the build is successful it should be a problem with your IDE, try invalidating the Cache and restart. 
I Also recommend you to download the DevKit plugin from `help -> install new software` in studio.

Cheers